# Two keys on keyboard suddenly switched roles

Tags: keyboard, catalina, keybindings

I have a Microsoft sculpt keyboard connect via usb to my Catalina MBP 16,1. Suddenly, the <kbd>^</kbd> key has traded roles with the <kbd><</kbd> key. The internal keyboard has the same problem. Everything else is the same, but those two have suddenly switched.

This came after an unsuccessful attempt to install [Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) which seemed super unstable. It did not occur right after that, as I used the keyboard for some time then.

How can I find out what the problem is, and fix it?

---

Update: After two rounds of reinstalling Karabiner, Uninstalling Karabiner, and Rebooting, the problem now only affects the external keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

When a new keyboard is connected, macOS will show the `Change Keyboard Type` button in System Preferences > Keyboard. This is used to detect the type of keyboard. For mine, it would have had to be ISO, but it seemingly got wrongly configured in the past, and the button would not show.

Deleting `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist` and rebooting made the button reappear and I could set up the keyboard correctly again.

Answer (score 0):

If you open up the terminal and search for org.pqrs files

```
mdfind org.pqrs
```

You will likely find some files that Karibiner left behind. Delete them